# Choose function values unmatched in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I am writing this macro to get values from pivot table and store them in cells near pivot table.
The problem is when any value written in choose function not found in pivot table,it is showing application-defined or object-defined error, I cannot remove the fields from choose as the value can be there when in future pivot table will be updated.

Any help will be appreciated in this regard.

```
For i = 1 To 8

  Set rng = Intersect(pt.PivotFields("Category").PivotItems("Technical").DataRange.EntireRow, _
  pt.PivotFields("Office").PivotItems(Choose(i, "Mum", "blore", "chen", "delhi", "chandigarh", "hyd", "pune", "noida")) _
  .DataRange.EntireRow, pt.PivotFields("Total").DataRange)

  If rng Is Nothing Then

  Else

    Worksheets(6).Range(Choose(i, "AF29", "AF23", "AF24", "AF25", "AF30", "AF26", "AF27", "AF28")).value = CInt(WorksheetFunction.Percentile(rng, 0.95))

  End If

Next i
```

Comment: Actually Choose() is not causing any error in your code.  Because Loop will go from 1 to 8 and Choose() will retrieve the concerned cell reference for that associated loop counter.

Comment: But in some cases value does not exist in that pivot table, how to skip the loop when the value is not found.Or is there any other way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Error Handler** to handle that issue.

```
For i = 1 To 8
    On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = Intersect(pt.PivotFields("Category").PivotItems("Technical").DataRange.EntireRow, _
        pt.PivotFields("Office").PivotItems(Choose(i, "Mum", "blore", "chen", "delhi", "chandigarh", "hyd", "pune", "noida")) _
        .DataRange.EntireRow, pt.PivotFields("Total").DataRange)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets(6).Range(Choose(i, "AF29", "AF23", "AF24", "AF25", "AF30", "AF26", "AF27", "AF28")).Value = CInt(WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Rng, 0.95))
    End If
Next i
```